# Copy Database with structure and data to other Database -

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make copy of live database with structure and data without mysqldump .All the data present in Live Database shall be copied to Copy_Live_Database using PHP .
 Please Help me to fix this.
My Live Database name is : Live_Database 
Copy Database : Copy_Live_Database.